# Paint gradient for multiple cells in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I like to paint multi cells in tablelayoutpanel. I know how to paint for rows and columns as a normal code below:

```
private void tableLayoutPane1_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row == 3 || e.Row == 4 || e.Row == 5)
  { 
    LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(e.CellBounds, Color.White,   Color.Transparent, 90F);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.CellBounds);
  }
}
```

But I want to have one rectangle gradient for 3 cells or rows, and other hand a merged gradient for 3 cells or multiple cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using the Paint event instead of the CellPaint event.  The trick is finding out the location of each cell in the table.  There are two functions hidden from Intellisense (`GetRowHeights()` and `GetColumnWidths()`) that can get you the row heights and the column widths, so you can calculate the location yourself:

```
void tlp_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  int[] rowHeights = tlp.GetRowHeights();
  int[] colmWidths = tlp.GetColumnWidths();

  int boxLeft = 0;
  int boxTop = 0;
  int boxRight = 0;
  int boxBottom = 0;

  Rectangle r = Rectangle.Empty;
  for (int y = 0; y < rowHeights.Length; ++y) {
    boxLeft = 0;
    boxRight = 0;
    boxBottom += rowHeights[y];
    for (int x = 0; x < colmWidths.Length; ++x) {
      boxRight += colmWidths[x];
      if (x == 1 && y == 3) {
        r.X = boxLeft;
        r.Y = boxTop;
      }
      if (x == 2 && y == 5) {
        r.Width = boxRight - r.Left;
        r.Height = boxBottom - r.Top;
      }
      boxLeft += colmWidths[x];
    }
    boxTop += rowHeights[y];
  }

  if (!r.IsEmpty) {
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(tlp.AutoScrollPosition.X,
                                  tlp.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
    using (var br = new LinearGradientBrush(
                          r,
                          Color.Red,
                          Color.Black,
                          LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal)) {
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, r);
    }
  }
}
```

I've included a call to `e.Graphics.TranslateTransform` in case the TableLayoutPanel control has any scrollbars.

Result:

[image]

For any flickering issues, try inheriting from the TableLayoutPanel in order to set its DoubleBuffered property to true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your code works correctly but I think there are 2 problem as follows:1) there is a new solution which I recently wrote with a short code, please see it. 2) and both of our codes in right to left mode have a little problem and need a new correction in code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Concept answer**

set each cell individually. the first cell should resemble the first third of your gradient the second cell the middle portion and so on.

set your colors manually with [System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(int,int,int,int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1k42eh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or one of the other overloads which ever one fits best

your code structure would change a bit:

```
if(first cell)...
if(second cell)...
```

wish I could help more but its been to long for me since I played with winforms

another way may be to draw your cells transparent and draw an appropriate sized rectangle behind them with the gradient you desire.

sorry I have no real code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this question with shortcode below:

```
int x, y, w, h;

private void tableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row == 1 && e.Column == 0)
  {
    x = e.CellBounds.X;
    y = e.CellBounds.Y;
    w = e.CellBounds.Width;
    h = e.CellBounds.Height;
  }

  if (e.Row == 2 && e.Column == 0)
  {
    h = h + e.CellBounds.Height;
  }

  if (e.Row == 1 && e.Column == 1)
  {
    w = w + e.CellBounds.Width;
  }

  if (e.Row == 3 && e.Column == 3)
  {
    Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
    LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(rc, Color.Blue, Color.White, LinearGradientMode.Vertical);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rc);
  }
}
```